# Start Daemon Not Working in my GUI?

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-gui, error-log

When I start the daemon from the GUI, it almost immediately turns itself off and I get the following in the log. Can someone translate this into layman's terms? Thanks:

```
2017-Jan-03 19:25:27.197263 ERROR C:/msys64/DISTRIBUTION-BUILD/src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:231 Failed to lock C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\.daemon_lock
2017-Jan-03 19:25:27.197263 ERROR C:/msys64/DISTRIBUTION-BUILD/src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:273 Failed to lock "C:\ProgramData\bitmonero"
2017-Jan-03 19:25:27.197263 Deinitializing rpc server...
2017-Jan-03 19:25:27.197263 Deinitializing p2p...
2017-Jan-03 19:25:27.212263 Deinitializing core...
2017-Jan-03 19:25:27.233265 Failed to deinitialize core...
2017-Jan-03 19:25:27.233265 Stopping cryptonote protocol...
2017-Jan-03 19:25:27.233265 Cryptonote protocol stopped successfully
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In layman's terms, cryptonote, which is used by monero, is unable to find or create the file `.daemon_lock`[1](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/6f539159e8d3b8d1613c26e0c07308482e84c8de/src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp#L231) and the directory `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero`[2](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/6f539159e8d3b8d1613c26e0c07308482e84c8de/src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp#L273). You can browse to `C:\ProgramData` to see if the `bitmonero` directory currently exists.

If it does exist from previously running the CLI version of bitmonero, this problem is likely caused by some lack of permissions where the GUI wallet is not seen as a user that's allowed write access to this folder in the `ProgramData` directory. From what I understand, only the user who creates the directory has write access[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22107884/2407742) by default, although I don't fully understand the restrictions set by Windows and monero. I would expect the GUI wallet is supposed have access.

While I don't know exactly where the conflict is, here are a couple of ways you can troubleshoot. Shutdown any monero programs currently running. Check the Windows Task Manager (ctrl + shit + esc) to make sure nothing like `monerod.exe` is currently running. You can try launching the GUI again and see if it is recognized as a user that has access this time. If it works, then stop here. If not, continue.

If it is still closing with the same error messages, make sure everything monero related is shutdown again. Rename the directory `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero` to something else like `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero-backup`. Now launch the GUI wallet which should be able to create this directory itself and you can test whether it launches okay.

**Important:** If you had previously synced the blockchain and want to restore it, the directory `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb` contains any blockchain data you had previously downloaded and synchronized. Particularly the file `data.mdb` contains your blockchain data. Shutdown any bitmonero related software first. You should be able to move the old `data.mdb` from your `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero-backup\lmdb` directory into the newly created `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb` directory. If the new `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb` contains `data.mdb` you can delete that before replacing it with your backup `data.mdb`. Then, delete `lock.mdb`  and run the GUI wallet. It will create a new `lock.mdb` file.

Comment: iyrin: Many thanks. That actually did the trick. For others, as iyrin said, you must use the task manager on Windows to make sure any monero related stuff isn't running undetected in the background. Mine was.. Also, when you replace the lmdb folder don't copy and paste as that will take a long time. Just cut and paste which happens immediately.

Comment: Why my monero files are forced to stop and looks like block blocks rising

Comment: ! Cannot execute "C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\monerod.exe"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Windows 10. I run daemon in compatibility mode Windows 8 and as an administrator

Answer (score 0):

I too had issues with the daemon not starting.  As I recall the log files noted port issues and the rings not saving.  Problem was solved by manually starting the monerod.exe as an admin and then opening the gui wallet.  Seems to be fine now.